# Javascript clear multi select boxes

Tags: javascript

I've 2 multiselect boxes one is with values and the second one is empty. When I choose option from the left and click arrow button it takes the value to the second one. My question is how can I clear it by a function in `button` and restore these values I mean get back the value to the first one and clear the second one. I tried like that but it does not work.

```
myOptions.options.length = 0;
myOptions.options[0] = new Option("", "");
```

Comment: we cannot imagine your code... show us full js code for it here using snippet or on jsfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple add/remove model using a click listener and two buttons.

In the example we look at the `selectedOptions` collection and move them.

```js
const moveFrom = (source) => {
  let target = (source === 'main') ? '#target' : '#main';
  target = document.querySelector(target);
  Array.from(document.querySelector(`#${source}`).selectedOptions).forEach(opt => {
    target.add(opt);
  });
};

document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if(e.target.matches('#add')) {
    moveFrom('main');
  }
  if(e.target.matches('#remove')){
    moveFrom('target');
  }
});
```

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
}

select {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <select id="main" size="5" multiple="true">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div>
  <button id="add">Add</button>
  <button id="remove">remove</button>
</div>
<div>
  <select id="target" size="5" multiple="true">
  </select>
</div>
```